# favicon.ico not visible on IE 11

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to add icon to html page.
Following is the code,

```
<link rel="icon" href="../../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Here I am trying to get favicon.ico from specific path.
This works on chrome but not on IE.
IE 11 version

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method:

```
<link rel="icon" href="url/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="url/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="ICON" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico"/>
```

Try any of these and check whether It worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried all three combination but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try this https://jay.lee.bio/blog/2013/04/30/the-definitive-way-to-create-a-favicon and also check the extension of your image whether it is .ico or not? Let me know then.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Basically, IE11 is fierce about caching the favicon. Adding a cache buster in the URL might fix it. Something like `../../images/favicon.ico?v=1`.

Another user also suggested removing `type="image/x-icon"`.

Comment: I tried this but no change still, I am not able to see icon on IE but for chrome all works fine