# How to change my website favicon with new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change my website favicon with the new icon image but I am unable to change it. It is still showing the previous one.

Previously when I added favicon with a `link` tag, which was suggested from many online resources, it had worked for me. However now when I am trying to replace it with a different one, it is not changing.
I followed a StackOverflow link [How do I force a favicon refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) but still, my problem remains as it is.

That Link tag in following format:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />
```

Comment: Assuming the path to the new favicon is correct, then It's most likely been cached by the browser. Clear the cache to see the change

Comment: you could try also hard refresh your browser:  Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force a favicon refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favicon is notorious for not refreshing, you can force your browser to redownload it by adding a querystring to your href path like so:

```
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="/somewhere/myicon.png?v=2" />
```

Also try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: by clearing browser cache, it will reflect to me only. how to make it for all my user

Comment: Adding the href path should force the browser to update it for all your users, as said in the first part of my answer.

Comment: but still it is not working for me

Comment: Try removing the type, leave the rel and href with v=2