# Customize favIcon.icon loading error with caching in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angular

I am using Angular framework and I have implemented a app for changing favicon. When I changed the icon by using app, it's not changed.When I clear the cache and reload, it worked well. But I want to do that when I save the new favicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh your favicon you can force browsers to download a new version using the link tag and a querystring on your filename.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: @OshadhaPunchihewa In my opinion you can check this question, it contain plenty of answers -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh/2208977#2208977