# changed the Vuejs tab icon in public/index.html , but it didn't change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, favicon

I've replaced the image with another one but it still doesn't change, I've removed "favicon.ico">" tab icon remains unchanged and not empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" mode="light">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>web</title>
  </head>
  <body class="sidebar-main-active right-column-fixed">
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue-dashboard doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing up the cache? CMD+SHIFT+R on mac

Comment: i use linux and already clearing cache in my laptop and browser but didn't change ;(

Comment: Have you seen this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

may work :)