# I was creating a website, but my favicon isn't working

Tags: html

I was creating a website, then I wanted to add a favicon to my site

I tried but it's not working

here's the code:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>
        My Site
    </title>
</head>
```

I have no idea what's going on

I don't see my favicon on my tab

you may ask "Is there a "favicon.ico" file in my folder?" (or something like that)
yes, there's already a "favicon.ico" file in my folder

any ideas?

Comment: Browsers cache icons and you may need to clear your cache to see your new icon. Does this answer your question? [How do I force a favicon refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Comment: Are you using the correct path to the icon? Can you show me the relative path where it is in your folder? It could be `/favicon.ico`