# favicon showing every time, when i open my index.html on my browser

Tags: html, indexing, favicon, visual-web-developer, ico

Why I get a single favicon every time. I am used this favicon in my last document but still, when I created a new document its showing although I don't use favicon link in my html document. Why? (How can I clear favicon cache).
I want a proper solution of this problem.
this is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello ji How are you all</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please Help anyone if you know solution..

Comment: Clear the cache and reload

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force a favicon refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)